# run apt-get with a different user

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

I have a script where I add a new user sudo and after I need to install packages.

Is that possible, to execute the apt-get as the new user?

For example, I'm logged with the user1. I run the script. In that script, I create user2 (sudoer). After, I want to install the new packages using user2

Do I only have to use that command line and it supposes to work?

```
sudo -u user2 apt-get -y install [packagename]
```

Comment: `apt-get` needs to run as root, so you'd still need to do `sudo -u user2 sudo apt-get -y install ...`, which defeats the point somewhat.

Comment: even if user2 is a sudoer?

Comment: Only if user2 is a sudoer. If user2 isn't a sudoer, they couldn't install using apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

You must run `apt-get` as `root` via `sudo`, not as another user.

Many of the actual directories maintained by `apt` for package information need `root` to maintained; as well, if a package is installing to `/bin` or similar it needs root.

Sudoers privilege only permits a user that is logged in to use `sudo` and to define what they can or cannot do with the `sudo` command. It does not grant the privileges that `apt-get` needs to operate as that needs the effective `root` permissions that just running `sudo apt-get` would provide.  Therefore if user1 is running `sudo apt-get` they would be allowed to.  If user2 is not in sudoers they can't execute that command. (But could if they were in sudoers).

---

To do what you are trying to do would need two `sudo` commands chained (untested by the way):

```
sudo -u user2 sudo apt-get -y install PACKAGENAME
```

Note though this is not typically how things should be run and that this could lead to possibly undefined behavior or weirdness.

user2 would also need to have permissions to execute as root, which may or may not be the case in the sudoers configuration.